# Como dar la ruta de una img en python PIL

Tags: python, pillow

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```py
from PIL import Image

imagen = Image.open("Users\matia\OneDrive\Escritorio\Matias\programacion\IA\opencv-learning\IMG\perro.jpg")
print(imagen)
```

Pero no logro ver la imagen.

Comment: Hola Matias, bienvenido a [es.so] ¿Cuál es el problema concreto o error que tienes??

Answer (score 0):

Hola si estas en Python 3  debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```py
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("C:\Users\matia\OneDrive\Escritorio\Matias\programacion\IA\opencv-learning\IMG\perro.jpg"")
im.show()
```

Debes tener en cuenta que la función `show()` tiene un comportamiento inestable y en algún escenario puede fallarte, asegurate primeramente de tener instalado `xv` si estas en Linux puedes emitir intentar con este proceso:

```sh
sudo apt-get install xli
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xli xv
```

Eso instala `xv` y podras ver la imagen con el método `show()`.